# Refresh Page-Based Application

Tags: swift, refresh, ios9, uipageviewcontroller

I'm parsing data over Parse.com, but I'm having trouble setting views dynamically and refreshing it over time.
Example: When I set 3 views it works fine. If I need to set more 2 views, I don't know how to do it.

There's a way to refresh it like a pull to refresh (in table view scope) or something?

I hope you did understand and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out. Add this code in your TableViewController

```
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull To Refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.resultsTable.addSubview(refresher)
}


func refresh(){
    //add code
}
```

Comment: Actually my question was about PageViewController refresh. After executing viewControllerAfterViewController, pageViewController is cached. I'm not sure how I can add pages later.